# Can I default DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate to all members inside a class?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a few class just for storing setting data for an application. I want to be able to default the

```
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]
```

to all member so that the whole class look a lot cleaner. Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, there's no relevant property on [`JsonObjectAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm).  You could do it with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) though.

Comment: If you want to do this for all classes, you can pass it as a setting to the serializer.

Comment: Thanks, I think its better to set it as a setting globally for my case.